# Laravel5 how to search in many blades

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I am new to laravel.I want to add search button in my application like search in all website ,when i write a word it will search it in all pages and return the page where the word  in red color. I make this code in layout

```
<form method="get" action="{{url('/create')}}">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search in site..." />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><img src="images/home/searchicon.png"></button>
</form>
```

and this in controller

```
public function create() {

        $search = \Request::get('search');
        ////how to search in all pages
    }
```

But I don't know how to search in all pages and this content isn't in database.
Am I use javascript or package in laravel or what?
please any one help me

Comment: Try Instant Search : https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/

Comment: I register in it how to use it ? how to get code from it?

Comment: Does this widget require saving all content of all pages in database or not?

Comment: I first time to use external js .does it require to download its files? or write<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.css" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.js"></script>in head only

Comment: Check the demo files and you will get the idea: https://github.com/algolia/examples/tree/master/instant-search/instantsearch.js